# Why can't I assign an ArrayList to a List variable?

Tags: java, generics

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<List<URL>> announces;
announces = new ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>>();
```

The error is the following:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>> to <List<List<URL>>
```

Answer (score 16):

Because your Generic is **bounded** to a type `List<URL>`. i.e. only `List` (which is an interface) is accepted.

You can allow any list by using [**wildcards**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

```
List<? extends List<URL>> announces;
```

---

You can also consider [**subtyping**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html). Example:

```
List<List<URL>> announces = new ArrayList<List<URL>>();
announces.add(new ArrayList<URL>());
announces.add(new LinkedList<URL>());
```

This is valid as the Generic type accepts a `List<URL>` and `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` *is-a* `List`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
List<? extends List<URL>> announces = new ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>>();
```

Comment: Or `List<List<URL>> announced = new ArrayList<List<URL>>()`;

Answer (score 0):

Because your type casting is wrong.

```
List<List<URL>> announces; announces = new ArrayList<List<URL>>();
```

Should work.
Doesn't matter the type of List you use. If you want to force using of ArrayList then use

```
List<ArrayList<URL>> announces;
announces = new ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>>();
```

In the first example, in your array list you can insert an array list and there should be no problem, but you can't change your declared Type check, What you are saying when you declare your variable is that I want to allow all sorts of lists but then the list you are setting in it only allows ArrayLists. Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

do

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>> announces = new ArrayList<ArrayList<URL>>();
```

Use interfaces for variables is nonsense. Obviously you are going to insert stuff into it, do yourself a favor, use exact types and you'll be happy. (You cannot insert into a `List<? extends List<URL>>`)

Now, if we expose this thing, like returning it from a method, then it becomes a problem what should be the proper type. `List<List<URL>>` is perfect. `List<? extends List<URL>>` is you are stoned.

Can we return the previously declared `announces` as a `List<List<URL>>`? Sure, why not. Just do a cast, we know it's safe. What if caller inserts a `LinkedList<URL>` into it? Who cares?

Comment: -1 for *Use interfaces for variables is nonsense.* You could just use `List<List<URL>> announces = new ArrayList<List<URL>>()`, and can insert any list in it, and don't need any cast then.

Comment: @palo-ebermann Try to retrieve an ArrayList from it. So tell me, what are you guys trying to achieve by this abstraction within an implementation? What is the point of hiding information from *yourselves*? Why obscurity where clarity is better? So you read it from a book. The book is wrong. When I first pointed this out on stackoverflow, I got annihilated. Now more and more people are getting my point.